# Change Stripe Checkout Button when Purchase completed

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to make my button say "Paid" or even get some sort of `console.log` back when a user has Paid via Stripe Checkout. My current code is looking like the following, but I'm getting the error `token is not defined` within my console errors.

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary text-white mt-3 btn-sm purchaseButton" data-amount="23.99" data-name="test" data-email="test@gmail.com" data-description="test">
    Accept & Pay (£23.99)
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
        key: 'pk_test_CF2GDj8RsSNWc23MhUJ9kylU00CkI1AJZ5',
        locale: 'auto',
        token: function(token) {
            // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
            // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
            chargeStatus(token);
        }
    });

    var buyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('purchaseButton');
    for (i = 0; i < buyButtons.length; i++) {
        buyButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            // Open Checkout with further options:
            handler.open({
                name: this.dataset.name,
                amount: this.dataset.amount,
                src: "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js",
                class: "stripe-button",
                key: "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh",
                email: this.dataset.email,
                currency: "gbp",
                description: this.dataset.description,
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        handler.close();
    });

    function chargeStatus(theObject) {
        fetch("/charge", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: JSON.stringify(theObject.id)
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok)
                throw response;
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(output => {
            console.log("Purchase succeeded:", output);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Purchase failed:", err);
        })
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `fetch` block is trying to access the variable `token` which doesn't exist in that scope. Your fetch should be executed after Stripe Checkouts returns a token for you to use. Wrap your `fetch` code in a function and call that function in your `token: function(token) {}` handler.

Comment: Hi Paul, I've edited the code and wrapped it within a function but unfortunately still comes back with `token is not defined`

Comment: In your `chargeStatus` function you are passing  `theObject` but still referencing `token`. Also you aren't passing anything into `chargeStatus`. Change `token` to `theObject.id` in `chargeStatus` and pass `token` into your `chargeStatus` function and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I've updated the code above. I'm now getting a JS error `POST http://domain.local/charge 400 (Bad Request)` but I'm guessing this is because I'm not on a secure https domain.

Comment: That just means that your browser can't hit `http://domain.local/charge`. Probably because your backend isn't set up to receive requests at that route. Checkout will work in http, but only for test mode. Once you go live you need to have SSL enabled.

Comment: Thanks Paul, is there anyway to stay on the same page and just change the button text?

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused here about what `fetch` does. It will perform an AJAX request to your backend with the token you created in its body. You won't navigate away from the page. Your backend would then take the token, process a charge and return something to your frontend (the `then` part of your `fetch` call). After you get a response from your server you can do what you like on your page.